# jQuery.each() class example Appending Div Text to Li

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[$EACH DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/v0m1nt8n/)**

anyhow iam getting the text of "div class": and printing in console., 
and iam trying to append the same text in "li > button", which is not happening, not sure where iam going wrong,

**html :**

```
<div class="productDescription">Red</div>
<div class="productDescription">Orange</div>
<div class="productDescription">Green</div>


<li><button>1</button></li>
<li><button>2</button></li>
<li><button>3</button></li>
```

**JS:**

```
//step - 1
$.each($('.productDescription'), function() { 
    var classTxt = $(this).text();
    console.log(classTxt);
});
//outputs: Red Orange Green

//step - 2 now im trying to append the text to li 
var liBtn = $(this).find('li').next('button');
    console.log("Text of Button - "+ classTxt);
    console.log(liBtn)
    for (var i = liBtn.length; i >= 0; i++) {
        liBtn[i]
    };
```

Appreciate Your Help, Thanks

Comment: classTxt is local variable to $.each function. which is not available out side.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code. `classTxt` is `undefined` outside of the `each` handler's context and the second `this` refers to `window` object and not to the `.productDescription` elements.

I'd suggest using the `.append()` method's callback function:

```
// cache the collection for better performance
var $p = $('.productDescription');

$('li button').append(function (index) {
    return $p.eq(index).text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46yo7etz/

You could also use the `.text()` method:

```
$('li button').text(function(index, currentTextContent) {
    // using indices for selecting 
    // the corresponding `.productDescription` element
    return currentTextContent + $p.eq(index).text();
});
```

Please note that your fiddle's markup is invalid. `li` element should be child of an `ul`/`ol` element.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('li > button').text(function() {
  return $('.productDescription').eq( $('li > button').index( this ) ).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productDescription">Red</div>
<div class="productDescription">Orange</div>
<div class="productDescription">Green</div>


<li><button>1</button></li>
<li><button>2</button></li>
<li><button>3</button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").each(function(i){
    $(this).text( $(".productDescription").eq(i).text() ); 
})

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productDescription">Red</div>
<div class="productDescription">Orange</div>
<div class="productDescription">Green</div>

<ul>
   <li><button>1</button></li>
   <li><button>2</button></li>
   <li><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/uqmpvb7e/